# Laravel 5.4.x ignores using method for pivot table definition

Tags: php, pivot, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have a model Contact, than can have many classifications, and I also have a Classification model than can be featured in many Contact. So you guessed, I have built the pivot table, for me its name is `classificationContact` (yes, no snake case, just camel).

Here is the Contact model definition:

```
<?php
    class Contact extends Model {
        // ...

        public function classifications() {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classification')
                ->using('App\ClassificationContact')
                ->withPivot('created_at');
        }
    }
?>
```

The Classification (but we do not pay attention, I only want to access my classifications through my Contact only):

```
<?php
    class Classification extends Model {
        // ...
    }
?>
```

And my pivot table have a model:

```
<?php
    class ClassificationContact extends Pivot {
        // ...

        protected $table = 'classificationContact'; // not taken into acount !
    }
?>
```

**PROBLEM**

When querying my relation, e.g. `App\Contact::find(1)->classifications`, Laravel gets angry and prompt:

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.classification_contact' doesn't exist

I am aware Laravel does snake case the pivot tables by default, but as I overrided the `protected $table` property I thought he would get this but I might miss something ?

**QUESTION**

How to force a table name for a Pivot table model when using `->using()` method ?

**NOTE**

I need to pass through a model and not using the second parameter of `belongsToMany` because my model does have a foreign key referencing the user that updates the contact's classification :

```
<?php
    class ClassificationContact extends Pivot {
        // ...

        protected $table = 'classificationContact';

        public function user() {
            // Need to be able to do
            // App\Contact::find(1)->classifications->first()->user->firstname
            return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        }
    }
?>
```

**NOTE 2**

Here is the database I want to modelize :

[image]

**NOTE 3**

As I was re-watching my database, I figured out I do not only need `classification` and `model` to be featured in my pivot, but also with `user`! So we are facing a triple-key pivot table. Here is my corrected database schema :

[image]

Laravel 5.4 here

Answer (score 0):

Add a second parameter to `belongsToMany` with the table name.

```
$this->belongsToMany('App\Classification', 'classificationContact')
     ->using('App\ClassificationContact');
```

Comment: Might not be the best case because my pivot table does have a foreign key I need to access (a user is binded to a "classificationContact"). I will add it to my question, thank you for your time.

Comment: This works as you force a table name, but the model provided in `using()` is still ignored, so weird!